# Constructors for Automatic Type Conversion when passing a built-in type variable to a "+" operator function having only one class-type argument

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

class test {
public:
    test() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            this->arr[i] = 0; 
    }
    test(int val) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            this->arr[i] = val;
    }
    test(int* a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
            this->arr[i] = a[i]; 
    }
    test operator +(test& sub) {
        int arr1[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            arr1[i] = this->arr[i] + sub.arr[i];
        }
        return test(arr1);
    }
    void display() {
        cout << "The array is: "; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            cout << this->arr[i] << "\t"; 
        }
    }
private: 
    int arr[5];
};

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    test obj1(5), obj2(1); 
    obj2 = obj1 + x; //Error here
    obj2.display();
    return 0; 
}
```

Which seeks to test overloading the "+" operator by adding the "arr" member variable of two objects, return an object with the result and assign it to obj2 in the main function. However, according to the book, "Absolute C++", it is also possible to pass an integer to the "+" function, as it is now, by first converting the integer, through a constructor in the "test" class, to "test" type given that this constructor accepts variable of type integer as its argument. Then, the resultant object which has the value of "x" will be passed to the "+" function and it would work as it should.

However, the code doesn't compile and I get an error for trying this: There's no "+" operator matching these operands. So, what could possibly be the problem in my code in interpreting the book's details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get a compilation error is because `operator+` accepts a non-const lvalue-reference.

If you change the signature of the operator to take a `const test&` it will be able to bind to an rvalue and this will compile.

```
test operator +(const test& sub) {
    ...
}
```

Since the method does not modify `sub` it should take a const-ref.

**Edit:**
The `const` keyword makes an important difference here because of the value category. First let's look at a simple example.

```
void foo(int& i) {
    i = 5;
}

int b;

foo(b); //this is ok
foo(7); //this is not ok
```

We specified that we wanted an lvalue reference. That means we can pass in a variable, but not a temporary. In this case the temporary is a literal, but it could also be the return value from another function.

If we go back to your question, when you write `obj1 + x` you are already aware that there is a conversion happening from `int` to `test`. The returned value of that conversion is a temporary value.

If we want to handle an rvalue (a temporary) we need to use an rvalue-reference.

```
void foo(int&& i) {
    i = 5;
}

int x;

foo(x); // Now this will fail instead
foo(5); // This will however work
```

When we use a `const&` we are saying that we will not modify the value, and since we have promised to not modify it, it does not really matter if it's a temporary or not. We are only going to read from it anyway.

That's why a `const&` can bind to either an lvalue or and rvalue.

```
void foo(const int& i) {
    std::cout << i;
}

int x = 7;

foo(x); // This will work
foo(17); // This will also work
```

Comment: But, isn't this a matter of choice whether I should modify my parameters to be constant or not? What does the "const" keyword indicate here?

Comment: It is a matter of choice. The reason I say should is because the idiomatic way of writing an `operator+` is to not modify the parameter. If I used your class and wrote `test3 = test1 + test2` and that modified either of `test1/test2` I would be very surprised. I will update the answer with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Terminology - `const int&` is also an lvalue reference; you can say "const lvalue reference" or "non-const lvalue reference" to distinguish.

Comment: @M.M Noted, not sure where/what in my answer you feel is misusing terminology though.

Comment: @super in the first two paragraphs for example, it implies that an lvalue reference is incorrect (but the correct fix is also an lvalue reference, just a const one) . Or maybe by "accepts an lvalue reference" you mean "accepts only an lvalue" .

Comment: @M.M Oh, I see. I meant "lvalue-reference", not "const lvalue-reference". I'm not used to hearing it used as refering to either one of the two.

Comment: So, even temporary allocated locations in the memory for hosting the value returned by functions are considered rvalues, too?

I thought only literals like (5, c) which do not have a memory location rvalues.

Comment: @tintan Loosely speaking, anything that you can't refer to with a name is an rvalue.